# Laravel Page Not Found 404 with vue instead of default blade template

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, http-status-code-404, inertiajs

I'm trying to create my 404 page with vue, but it keeps showing the default blade template  404.blade.php
I'm using Laravel 10 with vue3 & Inertia

I've created my Error.vue page into resources/js/Pages
This is my code in `Handler.php` to render my `Error.vue`

`Handler.php`

```
    public function render($request, Throwable $e)
        {
            $response = parent::render($request, $e);      
            $status = $response->status();
     if (!app()->environment(['local', 'testing']) && in_array($response->status(), [404, 403, 500, 503])) {
    
              return Inertia::render('Error', ['status' => $response->status()])
                    ->toResponse($request)
                    ->setStatusCode($response->status());
            } elseif ($response->status() === 419) {
                return back()->with([
                    'message' => 'The page expired, please try again.',
                ]);
            }
        return $response;
        }
```

`Error.vue`  created inside resources/js/Pages

```
<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'
import { Head } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
const props = defineProps({ status: Number })
const title = computed(() => {
  return {
    503: '503: Service Unavailable',
    500: '500: Server Error',
    404: '404: Page Not Found',
    403: '403: Forbidden',
  }[props.status]
})
const description = computed(() => {
  return {
    503: 'Sorry, we are doing some maintenance. Please check back soon.',
    500: 'Whoops, something went wrong on our servers.',
    404: 'Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.',
    403: 'Sorry, you are forbidden from accessing this page.',
  }[props.status]
})
</script>
<template>
    <Head title="Error" />
  <div>
    <H1>{{ title }}</H1>
    <div>{{ description }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

This code works correctly. I had an error in :
**if (! app()->environment(['local', 'testing'])**. Remove this condition if you are working in local.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, this code works correctly. I made a mistake at :
**if (! app()->environment(['local', 'testing'])**. Remove this condition if you are working in local.